# Remove UITabBarItem

Tags: iphone, uitabbar, uitabbaritem, iphone-sdk-4.1

How can I remove a `UITabBarItem` from a `UITabBar`?

I haven't tried anything, because I haven't found anything from Google searches or the documentation for `UITabBar`, `UITabBarController`, or `UITabBarItem`.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Hi @esqew, what have you tried already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I haven't tried anything, because I haven't found anything from Google searches or the documentation for `UITabBar`, `UITabBarController`, or `UITabBarItem`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[UITabBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has an [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSArray) collection of items. Since the items property is an NSArray and not an [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you'd have to construct a new NSArray from the existing one devoid of the object you want to remove, then set the items property to the new array.

```
/* suppose we have a UITabBar *myBar, and an int index idx */
NSMutableArray *modifyMe = [[myBar items] mutableCopy];
[modifyMe removeObjectAtIndex:idx];
NSArray *newItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:modifyMe];
[myBar setItems:newItems animated:true];
```

Comment: Remember, `-[NSArray mutableCopy]` is your friend. Also, don't overlook `-[UITabBar setItems:animated:]`.

Answer (score 4):

Mike Caron's advice [will throw an exception](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) if you intend to modify a tabBar that belongs to a controller.

> In iOS 3.0 and later, you should not
>   attempt to use the methods and
>   properties of this class to modify the
>   tab bar when it is associated with a
>   tab bar controller object. Modifying
>   the tab bar in this way results in the
>   throwing of an exception. Instead, any
>   modifications to the tab bar or its
>   items should occur through the tab bar
>   controller interface. You may still
>   directly modify a tab bar object that
>   is not associated with a tab bar
>   controller.

In this case `self.tabBarItem=nil` will remove it.

Comment: In iOS 11, self.tabBarItem=nil only makes the holding spot empty, it doesn't actually shuffle the items to fill the "removed" item. :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9908361/856925 has an answer that still works — remove the viewcontroller form the tabbarcontroller viewcontrollers list.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: this appears to not work in iOS 11. It was still good in iOS 10.

This is a moderately horrible answer, in my opinion, in part because it's subverting the human interface guidelines, but all the same it seems to work cleanly:

```
UITabBar *oldbar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBar *newbar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,oldbar.frame.size.width,oldbar.frame.size.height)];
NSMutableArray *olditems = [[oldbar items] mutableCopy];
[olditems removeObjectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *newitems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:olditems];
[newbar setItems:newitems animated:false];
[oldbar addSubview:newbar];
```

That layers it cleanly on top of the old tabbar, and it maintains its functionality.