# How to remove programmatically a tab bar item created in parent class NIB file?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitabbar, nib, uitabbaritem

Within my iPhone application I have a common tab bar with *three tabs* that is presented from several views after pressing a button. The approach I followed was the workflow of Tweetie application, described in [Robert Conn post](http://www.wiredbob.com/blog/2009/4/20/iphone-tweetie-style-navigation-framework.html).

Note that the main controller is a navigation controller; the tab bar is placed in a view controller's NIB file of the navigation stack, and the effect of switching between tabs is handled in a delegate didSelectItem method.

```
@interface GameTabBarController : UIViewController<UITabBarDelegate> {
  UITabBar *tabBar;
  UITabBarItem *lastGameTabBarItem;
  UITabBarItem *previousGamesTabBarItem;
  UITabBarItem *myBetsTabBarItem;

  NSArray *viewControllers;
  UIViewController *currentViewController;
}

@implementation GameTabBarController
  ...

  - (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    UIViewController *viewController = nil;

    // Get the view controller linked to the tab bar item pressed
    ...

    // Switch to the view
    [self.currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
    self.currentViewController = viewController;
  }

  ...
@end
```

Since the views of the tab bar must be customized according to the view controller the application came from, I have made this `GameTabBarController` a parent class with that NIB file that have the tab bar. Then, I have created several children classes:

```
@interface FirstGameTabBarController : GameTabBarController {
  ...   
}

@interface SecondGameTabBarController : GameTabBarController {
  ...   
}

...
```

My problem is that in some of the children classes I would like to remove the third tab of the NIB file associated with parent class. But since there is no UITabBarController involved, I cannot follow typical approaches you can found on the web, i.e. removing the view controller of the tab bar item.

How can I do that? Is it possible to remove elements that has been previously added in a NIB file?

Thanks!!

**UPDATE**
The solution was so easy... I have just to replace the tab bar items, instead of the view controllers:

```
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBar.items];
[items removeObjectAtIndex:2];
[self.tabBar setItems:items];
```

Thanks to @Praveen S for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The following code has the solution:

```
NSMutableArray *tbViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.tabBarController viewControllers]];
[tbViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:2];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:tbViewControllers];
```

Comment: This still works in iOS11, unlike some other ugly hacks. ^_^

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4**

```
func removeTab(at index: Int) {
    guard let viewControllers = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers as? NSMutableArray else { return }
    viewControllers.removeObject(at: index)
    self.tabBarController?.viewControllers = (viewControllers as! [UIViewController])
}
```

Comment: @Yawar in this case maybe you don't have a tabbarcontroller properly configured on your viewcontroller's hierarchy.

Answer (score 8):

This is what it works for me for **Swift 4 and 5**

1. Create a custom `UITabBarController` class.
2. Assign the custom `UITabBarController` class to the view on storyboard.
3. Remove the `UIViewController` on `viewDidLoad`:

   ```
   class TabViewController: UITabBarController {

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           self.viewControllers?.remove(at: 1)
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Works the way I expected. IMHO the best way to do it

Comment: is it safe to use it like this?

Answer (score 2):

You can hold a reference to that tab bar object in your class and perform the desired actions on it.

```
IBOutlet <Type> name;
```

Connect it via Interface builder and you can perform actions, and in your case you may be thinking of removing it from superview.

Comment: You point me in the right direction, though your answer was not exactly what I was looking for. I'm updating the question to post what I finally did.

Comment: You cannot remove a `UITabBarItem` from its superview directly because it is a `UIBarItem`, which inherits from `NSObject`, not `UIView`. You would have to iterate over the `UITabBar`'s subviews and figure out which one corresponds to the `UITabBarItem`, which would probably require private APIs.