# Hide item in UITabbar?

Tags: ios, uitabbar

Is it a way to hide / show UITabbar element? I know I can remove and add, but what about hide? Latter I might need to show it again.

```
tabBar1.items!.remove(at: 1)
```

Comment: You can't remove `UITabBar` item(s) like that. You'll get error: `Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.`. Instead of you should remove in this way: `self.viewControllers?.remove(at: 1)` inside your `UITabBarController`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037160/remove-uitabbaritem

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide/show `UITabBarItem` . The reason is `UITabBarItem` inherits from `UIBarItem` which further inherits from `NSObject`. Hence, there is no UIView (which contains `isHidden` property ) class in any of the inheritance level.

Answer (score 0):

If hide/show property given for tabBar items, there will be a blank space in tabBar which will give bad UI experience. So you can't hide/show tabBarItem as Aditya mentioned above.

But If you want to add a tabBarItem initially and want to make it enabled only after some time, add it to the tabBar in disabled state as like below example.

```
let tabBar = UITabBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 320.0, height: 44.0))

let tabItem1 = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .history, tag: 0) 

tabItem1.isEnabled = false

let tabItem2 = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .favorites, tag: 1)        

tabBar.setItems([tabItem1, tabItem2], animated: true)

//Enable your tabItem1 when needed
tabBar.items![0].isEnabled = true
```